# Spring Webservice - Send properties directly on SOAP message body without being wrapped on class

Tags: java, spring, soap, jaxb

I would like to know if someone can help me.

I have to call a SOAP endpoint with this structure:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ese="http://tsp-gate.globaltrustedsign.com/ESealPdf">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ese:Digest>YYYYYY</ese:Digest>
      <ese:Certificate>xxxxx</ese:Certificate>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Like you can see the fields are directly on the root of SOAP body.

I'm using the Spring WebserviceTemplate to make the requests. I'm also generating the classes based on the WSDL, but it's just generating this:

```
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    private final static QName _Digest_QNAME = new QName("http://tsp-gate.globaltrustedsign.com/ESealPdf", "Digest");
    private final static QName _Certificate_QNAME = new QName("http://tsp-gate.globaltrustedsign.com/ESealPdf", "Certificate");
    private final static QName _Signature_QNAME = new QName("http://tsp-gate.globaltrustedsign.com/ESealPdf", "Signature");


    public ObjectFactory() {
    }


    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://tsp-gate.globaltrustedsign.com/ESealPdf", name = "Digest")
    public JAXBElement<String> createDigest(String value) {
        return new JAXBElement<String>(_Digest_QNAME, String.class, null, value);
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://tsp-gate.globaltrustedsign.com/ESealPdf", name = "Certificate")
    public JAXBElement<String> createCertificate(String value) {
        return new JAXBElement<String>(_Certificate_QNAME, String.class, null, value);
    }


    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://tsp-gate.globaltrustedsign.com/ESealPdf", name = "Signature")
    public JAXBElement<String> createSignature(String value) {
        return new JAXBElement<String>(_Signature_QNAME, String.class, null, value);
    }

}
```

Now, I don't know how to build the request based on this, in a way I can use the method webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive().

I also would like to understand if the webserviceTemplate + the JaxbMarshaller just allow or limit the creation of the XML request wrapped in an object instance (annotated with @XmlRootElement).